# How can I mount a projector to a concrete ceiling?

Tags: concrete, ceiling, drill, mounting, cinderblock

I am in a dorm room and I am attempting to mount my projector and screen in my ceiling... As far as I can tell from just tapping the ceiling it is made of cinderblocks if that sounds right or something similarly tough.

I have absolutely no idea how to mount the projector and screen in the ceiling and would appreciate any help...

What tools would I use?
Since I don't own anything but a hammer and screw driver, would I be able to rent the tools? If so, where?

Comment: Better check with the school before drilling holes is their ceilings.

Comment: Thankfully, the school does not care :) I checked before I even bought the projector!

Comment: How heavy is the projector, and how many screw holes are in its mounting bracket? This will help determine the type & size of anchor you'll need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Berkeley, CA has a tool library for just this kind of rental.  Major home stores have rentals, and there are chains of rental shops like Hertz Rentals.

You'll need a drill, a masonry bit, and a concrete anchor.  Your local hardware store can supply the last two.  Each anchor will have a specified hole size.

The ceiling is almost certainly not cinderblock.  But it could be reinforced concrete, which is a good strong material to anchor to.

Comment: You'll want a hammer drill for this..

Comment: A rotary drill works just fine for small holes.  A pro would insist on something faster, but as long as you can go slowly (1-2 minutes per hole) rotary is good enough, and far easier to find.